# Adding Array[][] to ArrayList replaces and adds element, instead of just adding

Tags: java, android

I'm using an arraylist of arrays[][] for my app. The problem is when I add the second element to the arraylist is replaces the first (It also adds to the arraylist, then when the next element is added it replaces all elements and adds, this happens repeadtedly.

I'm not to sure what code to add, so I'll add anything I think is helpfull.

Initializing the arraylist:

```
 ArrayList<Bitmap[][]> levelTileList = new ArrayList <Bitmap[][]>();
ArrayList<Rect[][]> levelTileListRec= new ArrayList <Rect[][]>();
ArrayList<Bitmap[][]> levelFireList = new ArrayList <Bitmap[][]>();
ArrayList<Rect[][]> levelFireListRec = new ArrayList <Rect[][]>();
```

Adding the first element:

```
 lvldesign.addLevel();

    levelTileList.add(lvldesign.getAllLevelTiles());
    levelTileListRec.add(lvldesign.getTempTileRect());
    //fire rect and bitmaps
    levelFireList.add(lvldesign.getAllLevelFire());
    levelFireListRec.add(lvldesign.getTempFireRect());
```

Note it calls another class to get the element.
The class it call

```
 public Bitmap[][] getAllLevelTiles(){
    return tempTile;
}

public Rect[][] getTempTileRect(){
    return tempTileRect;
}

public Bitmap[][] getAllLevelFire(){ return tempFire; }

public Rect[][] getTempFireRect(){
    return tempFireRect;
}
```

Adding subsequent elements:

```
 lvldesign.addLevel();

            levelTileList.add(lvldesign.getAllLevelTiles());

            levelTileListRec.add(lvldesign.getTempTileRect());

          //fire rect and bitmaps
            levelFireList.add(lvldesign.getAllLevelFire());

            levelFireListRec.add(lvldesign.getTempFireRect());
```

Note all elements it calls is either Bitmap[][] or Rect[][].

As I already said the latest added element replaces all earlier elements and adds an element.
Please let me know if there's any other specific code you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Alright seems each time you add to the arraylist it must be seen as a new variables. So I added the following code to my add level(this code runs before the call.) and it works. So if you have the same problem just make sure each element is seen a new element.

```
    tempTileRect = new Rect[mapHeight][mapWidth];
    tempFireRect = new Rect[mapHeight][mapWidth];
    tempTile = new Bitmap[mapHeight][mapWidth];
    tempFire = new Bitmap[mapHeight][mapWidth];
```

Comment: It is less error-prone to avoid using the member variables altogether. Just make these local variables in the method that adds these. Actually, it would be a lot cleaner to create a class that wraps items that go together so you aren't having to coordinate two lists where the items have to correspond by index.